# internal json import in a library breaks when importing this library from a served app in nx

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my library I'm importing a json file which works correctly when running codes from this library (e.g. storybook, linter), but when I'm importing from this library in an app served by nx I get this error:

```
Cannot find module './example.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension.
```

Do I have to add `"resolveJsonModule": true,` in my tsconfig.json in the app as well? It feels like something that should be resolved in the library.

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this too...

Comment: Did you figure this out or open a bug? I'm running into this as well.

Comment: I only get it to work by sitting it in the application tsconfig

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a types file to your app (`typings.d.ts`)?

```js
declare module '*.json' {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add "resolveJsonModule": true to your compiler options

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
}
```

Comment: Did you even read my question?